# Duplicate CallRecords from MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have set up a webhook/subscription mechanism to receive push notifications of Teams calls. I am then passing those ID values to the CallRecord API endpoint to retrieve call data. This is then being streamed using Stream Analytics to a database.
Going through the data, there are lots of duplicate calls with the same call ID being pushed at various different times several hours apart in some cases.
I have noticed that the CallRecord API endpoint as of yesterday has been moved out of beta/preview. Is this a bug?

Comment: I am seeing this too, and I can confirm that the subscription ID is the same in each case.  Is there an explanation for this?  Is this expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Short version:
In my case what removed the duplicates was responding with status 200 ok at the end of my notificationUrl handler.

Long version:
I had the (same?) problem of receiving the same change notification for the same callRecord id and the same subscription every 5 minutes.
I was using a http triggered flow for the notificationUrl but only consumed the data and didn't respond.
Then I saw the Microsoft video introducing deltas and change notifications again and noticed that the azure function in their example responds with okay in the end.
After I added a http 200 response in my Flow, the duplicate change notifications stopped after the next run.